# can not get plus symbol from url using get method

Tags: php

I am working in php. I have passed below msg in url.

```
$message=MSUB REG A+
```

When I get this mseeage variable so it prints like

```
OUTPUT : MSUB REG A
```

Here I want (+) sign also. So what shoul I have to do?

I have used urlencode($message). But it prints like

```
OUTPUT :  MSUB+REG+A+
```

But here I want to seperate **MSUB** **REG** and **A+** so what should I have to do?

Comment: + is a special charachter in urls. it translates to a space when url decoded.

Comment: @r3wt See my upated question

Comment: you need to make sure that it is encoded when sending to the server by encoding spaces as `%20`

Comment: @r3wt But this url is called when sms is send through mobile.

Comment: @Uchiha so you can not get + sign after A

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rawurldecode();`

```
<?php
$userinput = "foo+bar@baz";
$userinput = urlencode($userinput);  //"foo%2Bbar%40baz";
echo rawurldecode($userinput); // foo+bar@baz

?>
```

**Note:**

rawurldecode() does not decode plus symbols ('+') into spaces. urldecode() does.

See [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php)

Answer (score 0):

You said

> But this url is called when sms is send through mobile.

If you send sms by yourself, you should encode string using [rawurlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) before adding to sms message.

```
$message = rawurlencode('MSUB REG A+'); // MSUB%20REG%20A%2B
```

So, the link will looks like this: http://your.website/?message=MSUB%20REG%20A%2B